# Jquery drop down list both get color green when selecet red

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi when i select red in the drop down list i still get the `backgroundcolor green` when i click on the `td` can someone help?

```js
$('document').ready(function (){
    if ($('#rood').val() == 'Rood'){
        $('td').click(function (){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        });
    }

    if ($('#groen').val() == 'Groen'){
        $('td').click(function (){
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        })
    }
});
```

```html
<h2>Color</h2>
<select>
    <option value="Rood" id="rood">Rood</option>
    <option value="Groen" id="groen">Groen</option>
    <option value="Blauw">Blauw</option>
    <option value="Geel">Geel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: If downvoting, please leave a comment why. While the question might not be very advanced, it is very clear, consise and answerable, and in my opinion does not deserve to be downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

You should validate the condition in the click handler.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Bind the click hanlder
    $('td').click(function() {
        //Fetch the value for select
        var value = $('select').val();

        //Fetch the value and compare          
        if (value == 'Rood') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        } else if (value == 'Groen') {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Yes. You are checking that the value of the option red is red, and the value of the option green is green. You are not checking which option is selected at all, and therefor red will always be red, and green will always be green, and the latest statement will be the one deciding the background color

Answer (score 1):

@Satpal s answer is correct, I just wanted to add an explanation as to why your code does not work.

1. You have not implemented any sort of listener to the select. The select will not react to any clicks, unless you tell it to react to clicks.
2. Your code will execute only once, at document ready. Here, your code will read like this:

if red == red set background color to red (sets background color to red always)

if green == green set background color to green (sets background color to green always)

Since no click function on the select has been added, the background color will never be set to anything other than the green color afterwards.